# Why is C language still used?

Tags: c++, c

If `C++` is supposed to be "the advanced version of `C`," why do people still code in `C`? I understand that C is a system language, but since anything that can be done in C can be done in C++. So why do some programmers/scientists prefer C++ to C?

Comment: `If C++ is supposed to be "the advanced version of C` - who supposed so?

Comment: It's mostly a superset of C, but that doesn't mean it's better or we should switch. Objective-C is a strict superset, but we're not flocking to that en masse.

Comment: C++ is object-oriented while C is a structured language. There are many differences in their application.

Comment: @Acme, The inventor of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup, once stated that C++ (C+1) was meant to be a language that combines all the features of C with a lot more, such as OOP structure, and works as fast as C.

Comment: @MarkGarcia hahaha that's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason for the abusive behavior by some of the commenters above. Just because you know more than someone doesn't mean you should make fun of that someone. Answer(s) aparently matter for the guy who asked the question, so if all you have to offer is your perverted behavior, better not answer and ruin someone elses day at all.

Comment: C++ offers extra ways to approach a problem (OOP, generic programming, limited functional programming) - without care and deep knowledge, that can become a distraction from actually solving it robustly, or lead to disparate design elements that are hard for team members to follow.  Further, exceptions, `new` and `delete` are central to idiomatic C++ usage, but in certain environments inappropriate - average C++ programmers may struggle more without Standard containers than C programmers who're probably more familiar with writing similar low-level code themselves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On reason may be that `C++` requires a more advanced runtime. This is required to manage constructors, destructors etc... Also, `STL` requires implementing.

`C` on the other hand is simpler. There is no complex runtime to implement. Smaller memory constrained operating systems, 'bare metal' firmware or some drivers may only require what `C` offers.

Even in `C++`, elements of `C` are still sometimes used. For instance, when linking to a method from a DLL, from a bootloader or something else for instance, `C` style naming may be preferred because the name is 'uncluttered'.

See more [information on 'extern "C"'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d.aspx) to understand how to use it with linking.